# No values being passed in my Modal

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I have been searching the whole night and Day trying to figure out why the code don't pass any value in my modal. what is wrong in my code? thanks

```
<a href="#UpdateCrop" data-toggle="modal" class="fetchCCropID" data-toggle="modal"  data-id="<?php echo $my_crop->cc_id; ?>"><?php echo $my_crop->main_crop; ?> </a>
```

Here is what's inside my modal:

```
<input type="text" name="crop_cultivated_id" id="crop_cultivated_id" value="" />
```

and my javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".fetchCCropID", function () {
 var myCCropId = $(this).data('id');
 $(".modal-body #crop_cultivated_id").val( myCCropId );
 $('#crop_cultivated_id').modal('show');
```

});

did i miss anything here? is there a required js version to follow?

i followed this fiddle. it works but not in my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/605/

Answer (score 0):

Try this check, if you are getting the alert with "id"

```
$(document).on("click", ".fetchCCropID", function () {
 var myCCropId = $(this).attr('id'); // used attr prop to get the Id.
alert(myCCropId); 
 $(".modal-body #crop_cultivated_id").val( myCCropId );
 $('#crop_cultivated_id').modal('show');
})
```

as well as check if this is in proper format - data-id="cc_id; ?>">main_crop; ?>

Comment: I have inserted alert(myCCropId); but the alertbox is not prompting so i guess I'm not entering to my js script?

Comment: So that's the issue.. try $('.fetchCCropID').click(function (){var myCCropId = $(this).attr('id'); // used attr prop to get the Id.
alert(myCCropId); 
 $(".modal-body #crop_cultivated_id").val( myCCropId );
 $('#crop_cultivated_id').modal('show')